# Flux doesn't automated pull deployment of new container images

Tags: kubernetes, flux

i want to ask about flux for gitops in kubernetes.
i have a problems about "Automated deployment of new container images" using flux

I use ecr as my image repository, but when i push a new container images, it doesn't replace to the newest image in my kubernetes. 
I already added `fluxcd.io/automated: true` in my kubernetes deployment yaml, but its doesn't work,

here below is my deployment yaml :

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    fluxcd.io/automated: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ny-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web-container
        image: xxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/my-app:6703dbf
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: aws-cred
```

logs from flux :

```
ts=2020-06-07T04:10:13.117058444Z caller=warming.go:198 component=warmer info="refreshing image" image=555730086661.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sunflower-web tag_count=3 to_update=3 of_which_refresh=0 of_which_missing=3

ts=2020-06-07T04:10:13.287139096Z caller=warming.go:206 component=warmer updated=555730086661.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sunflower-web successful=3 attempted=3
```

Thanks before

Comment: share logs from flux pods

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu

```
ts=2020-06-07T04:10:13.117058444Z caller=warming.go:198 component=warmer info="refreshing image" image=555730086661.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sunflower-web tag_count=3 to_update=3 of_which_refresh=0 of_which_missing=3


ts=2020-06-07T04:10:13.287139096Z caller=warming.go:206 component=warmer updated=555730086661.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sunflower-web successful=3 attempted=3
```

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu i've been update the question added logs from flux

Comment: you pushed the image with a new tag ?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu yes i push image with new tag

Comment: Is it a problem with a specific image or all other images as well from the same repo? what does fluxctl list-images shows?